# Checkbox to show as it is

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a checkbox in my asp.net application, which is checked by default (means the participants list will be shown on pageload). On checking the checkbox will show the list of participants name. But If the user unchecks it and this list should not show. The checkbox property should not change after any postback happens  How to do this?

```html
<input id="checkboxid" class="toggle" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
                            
<label for="checkboxid" class="lbl-toggle">Participants</label>
```

Comment: What *specific* technology are you using, webforms, MVC, Blazor, ...?

Comment: If you use a asp.net checkbox, then the setting will persist and automatic survive a post-back